# MVC4 - Submit a form using multiple div onclick

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, migration

I'm migrating from a legacy ASP.NET website to MVC with Razor. I have, on the old site, a form with some `div` which submit my form. Here is the generated code in ASP.NET :

```
<form>
    <div id="choice1" onclick="__dopostback(...)">Choice 1<div>
    <div id="choice2" onclick="__dopostback(...)">Choice 2<div>
    <div id="choice3" onclick="__dopostback(...)">Choice 3<div>
    ...
</form>
```

Every `div` have it's own background image, animations, and so on; so I can't "translate" this with buttons. I don't have any problem to submit the form with a `onclick` attribute, but I don't know which `div` have been clicked... `__dopostback` set hidden variables in javascript with the name of the `div` before submiting the form to simulate an event; and I will probably reproduce this in MVC.

I think anyway there should be a cleaner way. Am I wrong ?

Comment: have you try this within the onclick event. using this you can get DIV id

Comment: I can't, since I use Razor in the new website, which doesn't support events. Or do you mean passing the id in the javascript event ?

Comment: Can you post the __dopostback(...) with parameters

Comment: @PEO means you can do `__dopostback(this.id)`

Comment: See my updated question, the code I've posted is generated with ASP.NET, not with MVC; so the __dopostback doesn't exists anymore.